# How to edit one specific row in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008, is there a secret to be able to edit one row based on a key?

There's an option to do "Edit Top 200 Rows", but what if I want to select some other row and edit it in the datagrid? I would rather do that than code an update statement and risk messing up the where clause.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Use the "Edit top 200" option, then click on "Show SQL panel", modify your query with your WHERE clause, and execute the query. You'll be able to edit the results.

Comment: Thanks! And just to add the keyboard shortcuts (SQL Server 2012 - not sure about previous versions) After using the "Edit top 200" option, you can press CTRL-3 to edit the query, CTRL+R to run the query.

Comment: For a more visual way of doing it, right next to "Show SQL Pane", there is a button for "Show Criteria Pane"; this lets you add filters based on a grid interface.

Answer (score 103):

How to edit one specific row/tuple in **Server Management Studio 2008/2012/2014/2016**

**Step 1:** Right button mouse > Select "Edit Top 200 Rows"

[image: Edit top 200 rows]

**Step 2:** Navigate to Query Designer > Pane > SQL *(**Shortcut: Ctrl+3**)*

[image: Navigate to Query Designer > Pane > SQL]

**Step 3:** Modify the query

[image: Modify the query]

**Step 4:** Right button mouse > Select "Execute SQL" *(**Shortcut: Ctrl+R**)*

[image]

Comment: But then it says: "The change has not been committed to Database"

Comment: Good answer but what a dumb interface design.

Comment: Thanks much for describing this so well!

Answer (score 3):

The menu location seems to have changed to:

Query Designer --> Pane --> SQL

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, but this is not an answer. If it is correct this should probably be edited into the existing answer, but of course with mention of from which version this applies.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer.

Comment: ѺȐeallү's newer answer also reflects this change in the menus. Note I'm using Server Management Studio 11.0.x (SQL Server 2012). As ѺȐeallү details very well with steps and screenshots, the menu location has been moved to: Query Designer --> Pane --> SQL

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing challenges in saving data from the results pane after using Edit Top 200 Rows option, then the below steps are for you:

1. Run the query or view that has the data you want to edit.
2. Navigate to the cells containing the data you want to change.
3. Type in the new data.
4. Save your changes by leaving the row.

Ref: [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/visual-db-tools/edit-rows-in-the-results-pane-visual-database-tools?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Welcome, but since there were several good answers with pictures on this post, no need for another one that doesn't provide any new or additional information.